# Listview DataPager with ObjectDataSource problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listview, datapager

I was added the DataPager Control inside Listview. There is no problem while displaying the data. But When I click the Next page button I m getting error.

Error: The Select operation is not supported by ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource2' unless the SelectMethod is specified.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if(!IsPostBack)      
        FillGrid();
        }

        private void FillGrid()
        {           
            User user = new User();
            user = (User)HttpContext.Current.Session["login"];
            ObjectDataSource2.SelectMethod = "GetDetails";
            ObjectDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("Customer_ID", DbType.Int32, Convert.ToString(user.Customer_ID));
            ObjectDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("Selected_Period", DbType.String, Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["period"]));
            ObjectDataSource2.TypeName = "Online.Lib.Invoice";

        }
```

CodeBeside:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
       <LayoutTemplate>            
                <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" PagedControlID="ListView1"   runat="server">
                <Fields> 
               <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10" />       
               <asp:NextPreviousPagerField FirstPageText="İlk" LastPageText="Son" NextPageText="İleri" PreviousPageText="Geri" />
              </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>                                                  
            </LayoutTemplate>  
   </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Seems clear: you should set the SelectMethod property on ObjectDataSource2 so it can load anything. If that doesn't work, please also post the ASP.NET markup for the ObjectDataSource...

Comment: @Koen Already defined SelectMethod property in FillGrid method.

Comment: Don't know if that should work like that. It's better to define it at the declaration. If you have different select methods that should be used in a page scope, you should use different ObjectDataSources as well. It's also better to set as many parameters as you can by declaration...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Your FillGrid() works well and you can load it's data by the Page_Load routine. When you click "Next page" of the ListView, you're doing a PostBack.

```
if(!IsPostBack)      
  FillGrid();
}
```

..Which means FillGrid() aren't loaded (which is the place ObjectDataSource have it's Select instruction). That's out of what I can see in the code snippets above. Quite common to make such mistakes in IsPostBack handling.